# "CountA" and IF functions to find specific data

Tags: excel

So I'm trying to count data over a large date range, lets say I only need May's data and only the data in May that has a field with a specific entry, I know I need to use COUNTA as the entry are words, but how would I organize the formula? IF (date matches range) then COUNTA IF (cell "X" = Yes) is the best I can come up with as the layout, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: you need countifs can you show some data?

Comment: =IF(Sheet2!$AE$2:$AE$5000>DATE(2017,5,1),A1<DATE(20017,5,31)),COUNTA," ")

Is what I'm trying to use, I see that countif is an option, but what would the criteria be, can I get it to return a count of anything that falls in that date range from said column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use =COUNTIFS(...). It allows you to use multiple sets of criteria.

For example, you could use something like this

```
=COUNTIFS(A1:A40,"Yes", B1:B40, ">"&C1)
```

It would tell you the number of fields with text "Yes" in A1:A40 that have a date in column B greater than the value of C1

Comment: Lets see if I can say this more clearly =D,

Example:
I have column E that has all my dates a job was scheduled, I need to count the number of jobs in column E that fall in a specific date range, such as 5/1/2017 through 5/31/2017, I think the count if will still work here, but I cant seem to get the criteria to use the range of dates.

Comment: Try something like this.
=COUNTIFS(E1:E40, ">"&J1, E1:E40, "<"&K1)

Enter your min and max dates in J1 and K1

Answer (score 0):

You can use COUNTIF as per the screenshot below. This will give you the number of  'May' entries in Column A:

[image]

In case you need to find another data in some other columns based upon the condition in column A then it would be a different solution. You will need to explain the problem a bit more clearly with some sample data.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
=COUNTIFS(Sheet2!$A$2:$A$5000,">="&DATE(2017,5,1),Sheet2!$A$2:$A$5000,"<="&DATE(2017,5,31),Sheet2!$B$2:$B$5000,"<>")
```

change A2:A5000 to your date column
B2:B5000 to your project column
instead of "<>" write the condition for project